# Firefox Add-on SDK open html file in https mode for gUM

Tags: firefox, https, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, getusermedia

I am creating a Firefox screenshot plugin for which I need to open an html page rendering screen share in https ()

Locally using AddOn SDK, my url of opened html file is :  **resource://jid1-q3wuqdulcvnnrq-at-jetpack/toolbar_button/data/index.html**

Now, on this link I get an error :

```
 In about:config, please enable media.getusermedia.screensharing.enabled
and add this site's domain name to media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains in about:config
```

Is there some way to set **tab.open(){}** such that it is rendered in secure mode.
Ref. :  [This page](http://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html) 
Clicking the Window button on above link redirects page to https mode for screen sharing.

Also in about:config => media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains => need to allow resource file domain.

Can someone please guide to enable getUserMedia on firefox.

Comment: try asking also at https://ask.mozilla.org

Comment: thanks @Noitidart for responding. I guess thats the last stop

Comment: sometimes they takea while but they have the people that know the internals so they will eventually respond. you can get on irc and ask people to take a look at your topic too :) but downside is you have to wait all day and stay online on irc, and hope for response and then keep trying.

Comment: Yes indeed. To cut the time, I have hosted my local file on a test server. And can see the file functioning there perfectly. However it has been authenticated by Basic HTTP Authentication. So now working on opening the hosted file with authentication within the add-on.

Comment: Ask on irc.mozilla.org in #media (preferably in European-friendly times for this question, m-f)